# Create a Windows Web Service to Copy New Files to Another Directory

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have an application that reports errors (in the form of XML files) to an import error folder. The files are quickly moved into an FTP.

The service that runs to cut and paste the files up to FTP runs every 30 seconds so task scheduler or any other scheduled service will not suffice.

I have been looking at using a web service to monitor the folder and copy the files into another location as they hit the import errors folder.

Using a little Google Fu I have see this can be performed using .NET. Having had only a little experience with .NET and VS I wanted to see if anyone could provide any advice on this?

Help?

Comment: `FileSystemWatcher` should suffice.  Have you made any attempts at your own code?

Comment: Have you though about a Windows Service instead?

Comment: @gravity thanks for the feedback. I have been looking at FileSystemWatcher. I think this may be the ticket. I haven't yet done any coding. I have a rough understanding of C# so will try knock something up. Once I have compiled the code what is the best way of setting up the service?

Comment: @stuartd yes, I understand there's quite a few ways to implement this. SRVANY being one of them. What would you recommend?

Comment: Most definitely [Topshelf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Topshelf/) - runs as a console app in development, then frictionlessly installs as a service.

Comment: @stuartd looks good. I will take a look. I was hoping for a solution only using the tools on Windows Server however. Is this not easily achievable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Windows Service template of Visual Studio:

[image]

And use the overrided methdos `protected override void OnStart(string[] args)` and `protected override void OnStop()` to start the main thread of your service and stop it.

Comment: Thanks, I guess for us low paid peeps this isn't an option in VS Express

Comment: Currently this screen shot is from an VS2015 community edition. I have many Windows service coded with this version of VS

Comment: Ah! I hadn't installed the '.NET desktop development' project templates. Once I done this, I could see the 'Windows Services 'option. OK, here we go...

Comment: Ok, you got it!